# Click to appendTo and again click undo it

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code when I click, an element [.topmenu] appendTo another element [.mainmenu] and I want to when click again, it is undone and the element goes back to first place [first place is on header .container]

But it doesn't work

```
$(function() {
        $(".navbar-toggle").Toggleclick(
            function(){ $(".topmenu").appendTo(".mainmenu"); },
            function(){ $(".topmenu").appendTo(".container"); },
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Toggleclick()` method in jQuery.

To make this work you would need to use a single `click` event handler which determines the current location of `.topmenu` and toggles the append location accordingly, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $topmenu = $('.topmenu'),
    $mainmenu = $('.mainmenu'),
    $container = $('.container');

  $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
    var $target = $topmenu.parent().is('.container') ? $mainmenu : $container;
    $topmenu.appendTo($target);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">Toggle</button>

<div class="mainmenu">
  Main menu
  <div class="topmenu">
    Top menu
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  Container
</div>
```

Comment: can we get a condition for this code that just do while max-width:767px ?!